# How to close an open PowerShell WPF Dialog without using a button

Tags: wpf, powershell

Hi there I am launch a WPF Dialog from PowerShell with other processes controlled in a Do While loop. On exiting the loop I am hoping to close the open Dialog. Here is some of the relevant code used.

```
    Function New-WPFDialog {
    
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
     This neat little function is based on the one from Brian Posey's Article on Powershell GUIs
    
    .DESCRIPTION
     AW re-factored a bit to return the resulting XaML Reader and controls as a single, named collection.

    .PARAMETER XamlData
     XamlData - A string containing valid XaML data

    .EXAMPLE

      $MyForm = New-WPFDialog -XamlData $XaMLData
      $MyForm.Exit.Add_Click({...})
      $null = $MyForm.UI.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{$MyForm.UI.ShowDialog()}.Wait()

    .NOTES
     Place additional notes here.

    .LINK
      http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/building-powershell-gui-part2.html

    .INPUTS
     XamlData - A string containing valid XaML data

    .OUTPUTS
     a collection of WPF GUI objects.
    #>
    
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, HelpMessage = 'XaML Data defining a GUI', Position = 1)]
        [string]$XamlData
    )
    
    # Add WPF and Windows Forms assemblies
    try {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase, system.windows.forms
    }
    catch {
        Throw 'Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework assemblies.'
    }
    
    # Create an XML Object with the XaML data in it
    [xml]$xmlWPF = $XamlData
    
    # Create the XAML reader using a new XML node reader, UI is the only hard-coded object name here
    Set-Variable -Name XaMLReader -Value @{ 'UI' = ([Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((new-object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xmlWPF))) }

    # Create hooks to each named object in the XAML reader
    $Elements = $xmlWPF.SelectNodes('//*[@Name]')
    ForEach ( $Element in $Elements ) {
        $VarName = $Element.Name
        $VarValue = $XaMLReader.UI.FindName($Element.Name)
        $XaMLReader.Add($VarName, $VarValue)
    }

    return $XaMLReader
}

    Function New-PopUpWindowAlertFixed {
    param(
        [string]
        $MessageText = "No Message Supplied")

    # This is the XaML that defines the GUI.
    $WPFXamLAlertFixed = @'
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="#006373"
        Width="300"
        Height="300">

    <ContentControl Foreground="White">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#006373" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock Name="Message10" Margin="20,32,20,20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Session Manager" FontSize="18"/>
            </StackPanel>
            

        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>

</Window>
'@
    
    $WPFGuiAlert2 = New-WPFDialog -XamlData $WPFXamlAlertFixed
    $WPFGuiAlert2.Message10.Text = "Session Manager"
    # $WPFGuiAlert.ApplicationExitCode = 99
    
    <#  CODE  #>

    $null = $WPFGUIAlert2.UI.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{ $WPFGuiAlert2.UI.Show() }.Wait()
    

}

    Do {
    
    New-PopUpWindowStart

    If ( $Script:VarStart -eq $true ) { 

        New-PopUpWindowAlertFixed
        

        $Script:VarLoop = 1

        <# I'd like to close the Dialog here #>

        
    }

} While ( $Script:VarLoop -eq 1 )
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can close the dialog without using a button. The dialog is launched using:

```
$null = $WPFGUIAlert2.UI.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{ $WPFGuiAlert2.UI.Show() }.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing:

```
$WPFGuiAlert2 = New-WPFDialog -XamlData $WPFXamlAlertFixed
```

to

```
$Script:WPFGuiAlert2 = New-WPFDialog -XamlData $WPFXamlAlertFixed
```

then closing the dialog with:

```
$WPFGuiAlert2.UI.Close()
```

My error detailed null expression so realised my variable was out of scope.